# How to generate a flag to determine which database a table is in?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that consists of two columns, DatabaseName and TableName. Some tables are in more than one database. What I would like to do is write a query that returns distinct TableName and three new columns that contain a `Y` if it is in the corresponding database or an `N` if it does not. To clarify, a table can appear more than once in the TableName column but will have something different in the DatabaseName column for each entry. Basically I want a list of the tables and an easy way to see which databases it is in.

I tried something like this:

```
sel distinct tablename, case when databasename='DB1' then 'Y' else 'N' end as DB1,
case when databasename='DB2' then 'Y' else 'N' end as DB2,
case when databasename='DB3' then 'Y' else 'N' end as DB3
from db.table_analysis
```

but it of course doesn't combine the rows with the same tablename together.

Comment: You are close, just need add `GROUP BY tablename`. Next time remember include dbschema and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tablename, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN databasename='DB1' THEN 1 END) > 0 
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
       END as DB1,
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN databasename='DB2' THEN 1 END) > 0 
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
       END as DB2,
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN databasename='DB3' THEN 1 END) > 0 
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
       END as DB3
FROM db.table_analysis
GROUP BY tablename
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: No need for `COUNT`, you can simply switch to `max(CASE WHEN databasename='DB1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)`